# Function list of nontraditional JavaScript methods in Xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode

When working on .js files in xcode, the method browser works and list traditional functions. Such as:

```
function OBj (e){
        for (var i in e) {
            enyo.log("element ", i, " is ", e[i])
        }
    };
```

or...

```
var OBj = function(e) {
        for (var i in e) {
            enyo.log("element ", i, " is ", e[i])
        }
    };
```

But what about other patterns?.... such as:

```
Obj.method({

    init: function() {},
    data: function() {},

})
```

This is where xcode falls short for me. So in this question/answer post, I present a shell script which I wrote in order to provide the type of method navigation which I needed for the javascript pattern type that I used. Utilizing the marker `???` feature in xcode, the shell script simply loops through all .js files in a specified folder, and by way of pattern matching it seeks out all methods that adheres to the pattern:

```
init: function() {},
```

It injects a *commented* matching marker so you would now have:

```
Obj.method({

//???:init
    init: function() {},
//???:data
    data: function() {},

})
```

Which happily shows up on xcode's method drop down list:

[image]

---

I have provided the script as the answer part to my question. Simply copy and paste into a file. Put that file inside the folder where your JS files are located. From the terminal, `cd` to that folder and run the shell script: `./scriptname`

Golden!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ***WARNING: BACK UP YOUR FILES BEFORE RUNING THIS SCRIPT ON THEM

# JS function pattern
v1=': function'

# Change these to point to the paths of your own JS files
temp_file='/Users/.../Documents/.../www/.../'
jsfolder='/Users/.../Documents/.../www/.../'


# Do not change anything below unless you know what you doing,
# as it will likely break the script.   
v2="\/\/\?\?\?\:"
temploc='temp_file'
for i in "${jsfolder}"*.js
do
sed -e  's/'"${v2}"'.*//' -e 's/ *\([^: ]*\)'"${v1}"'.*/'"${v2}"'\1\
&/' $i > $temp_file$temploc
mv $temp_file$temploc $i
done
```